# How to get a list with elements that are contained in two other lists?

Tags: python

We have two lists:

```
a=['1','2','3','4']
b=['2','3','4','5']
```

How to get a list with elements that are contained in both lists:

```
a_and_b=['2','3','4']
```

and a list with elements that are contained only in one list, but not the other:

```
only_a=['1']
only_b=['5']
```

Yes, I can use cycles, but it's lame =)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply with the use of sets:

```
>>> a=['1','2','3','4']; b=['2','3','4','5']
>>> a = set(a)
>>> b = set(b)
>>> a & b
set(['3', '2', '4'])
>>> a - b
set(['1'])
>>> b - a
set(['5'])
>>>
```

Answer (score 8):

if order is not important

```
>>> a=['1','2','3','4']
>>> b=['2','3','4','5']
>>> set(a) & set(b)
set(['3', '2', '4'])
```

only a

```
>>> set(a).difference(b) # or set(a) - set(b)
set(['1'])
```

only b

```
>>> set(b).difference(a)  # or set(b) - set(a)
set(['5'])
```

Comment: you don't need to cast to set `.difference` argument.

Comment: yes, we don't need to, but some one may like to look at words. :)

Comment: What SilentGhost means is you can do `set(a).difference(b)`